# Send T type to method with an object Instance

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, system.reflection

I'm sorry if I can't explain my question but it's hard for me.

I'm trying to send an T class to my method, but I don't have direct access to my object, so, I thought use the name for create an instance with reflections, but I don't know how to send the class `T` to my method.

This is th definition of my method

```
void RedirectToActivity<T>(bool closePrevious);
```

And I have this code for call it

```
var activity = Activator.CreateInstance("myassembly", "MainActivity");
RedirectToActivity<????>(true);
```

With the first line I create an Instance of my class `MainActivity`.

In second line I need to send `MainActivity` class, and receive it like a `T` object in `RedirectToActivity`, but I don't know how to achieve this.

I need some like that...

```
RedirectToActivity<MainActivity>(true);
```

But I don't have direct access to MainActivity class.

I've tried this

```
RedirectToActivity<activity.GetType()>(true);
RedirectToActivity<typeof(activity)>(true);
```

But not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just add a generic parameter argument to your `RedirectToActivity` method?

```
void RedirectToActivity<T>(T activity, bool closePrevious)
{
    // Do Stuff here
}
```

And then pass your activity instance in:

```
var activity = Activator.CreateInstance<MainActivity>();
RedirectToActivity(activity, true);
```

Comment: Ok, it's not like I thought, but I can change my implementation according to your answer. It like me